# Limiting results displayed from jquery sorted list of most upcoming events

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am working in Adobe Business Catalyst, and I needed a way to sort results from a client's entries. They are wanting to display the movies that are Coming Soon, I found this great piece of code for sorting the items.

http://jsfiddle.net/thetrickster/7U3Xd/

```
<ul class="sort-list">
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14-Feb-2013">Valentine's Day on 14-Feb-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25-Dec-2013">Christmas on 25-Dec-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14-Jul-2013">Bastille Day on 14-Jul-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01-Jan-2013">New Year's Day on 01-Jan-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="31-Oct-2013">Halloween on 31-Oct-2013</li>

</ul>
(function($){
    var container = $(".sort-list");
    var items = $(".sort-item");

    items.each(function() {
       // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
       // standardized date format
       var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("-");
       var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];
       standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
       $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

    });


    items.sort(function(a,b){
        a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
        b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
        return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
    }).each(function(){
        container.prepend(this);
    });

})(jQuery);

/* This script sorts your list in descending order... to change it to ascending order change the "less than" operator (<) to "greater than" (>) */
```

This works perfectly for the page where we have all of the items listed, but the next step would be getting only the 4 most upcoming items to display on the homepage. Is there a way to add a count or limit the items AFTER they've been sorted by date?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (untested). Just a simple counter added. This would be a perfect case to use [Angularjs filtering & sort](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/filtering-and-sorting-a-list.html).

```
<ul class="sort-list">
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14-Feb-2013">Valentine's Day on 14-Feb-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25-Dec-2013">Christmas on 25-Dec-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14-Jul-2013">Bastille Day on 14-Jul-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01-Jan-2013">New Year's Day on 01-Jan-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="31-Oct-2013">Halloween on 31-Oct-2013</li>

</ul>
(function($){
    var container = $(".sort-list");
    var items = $(".sort-item");

    var count = 0;
    var limit = 4;

    items.each(function() {
       // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
       // standardized date format
       var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("-");
       var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];
       standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
       $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

    });


    items.sort(function(a,b){
        a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
        b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
        return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
    }).each(function(){
        count ++
        if(limit && count <= limit){
            container.prepend(this);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

/* This script sorts your list in descending order... to change it to ascending order change the "less than" operator (<) to "greater than" (>) */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array filter function:

```
(function($){
    var container = $(".sort-list");
    var items = $(".sort-item");

    var count = 0;
    var limit = 4;

    items.each(function() {
       // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
       // standardized date format
       var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("-");
       var standardDate = BCDate[1]+" "+BCDate[0]+" "+BCDate[2];
       standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
       $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

    });


    var topItems = items.sort(function(a,b){
        a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
        b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
        return a>b ? -1 : a<b ? 1 : 0;
    }).filter(function(item, index){
        return index < 4;    // filters the array to only items with index 3 or less i.e. the top 4
    }).each(function(item){
        container.prepend(this);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take advantage of the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) parameters:

- index,
- element

To get the right result, using the prepend, you need to invert the order of sorting from:

```
return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
```

to:

```
return !(a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<!--

In your web app list layout you can use the following markup:

<li class="sort-item" data-event-date="{tag_event date}">
    YOUR OTHER WEB APP TAGS HERE
</li>

This will work with your custom event date if your field is called "Event Date".  If it has a different name, just insert your custom tag in the "data-event-date" attribute.

-->


<ul class="sort-list">
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14-Feb-2013">Valentine's Day on 14-Feb-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="25-Dec-2013">Christmas on 25-Dec-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="14-Jul-2013">Bastille Day on 14-Jul-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01-Jan-2013">New Year's Day on 01-Jan-2013</li>
    <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="31-Oct-2013">Halloween on 31-Oct-2013</li>

</ul>

<script>
    (function ($) {
    var container = $(".sort-list");
    var items = $(".sort-item");

    items.each(function () {
      // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
      // standardized date format
      var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("-");
      var standardDate = BCDate[1] + " " + BCDate[0] + " " + BCDate[2];
      standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
      $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);

    });


    items.sort(function (a, b) {
      a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
      b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
      return !(a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0);
    }).each(function (index, element) {
      // 
      // parameters: index, element
      //
      if (index < 4) {
        container.prepend(element);
      } else {
         $(element).hide();
      }
    });

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```